# Restangular .getList() or get() not working when chained with .then() in controller, but works if resolved in routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I want to be able to have exception handling when using `getList()` or `get()` however if I user `then()` nothing useful is returned. If remove `then()` then it returns what I'm expecting, but I don't have exception handling.

Restangular's own [documentation](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#lets-code) uses `then()` with `getList()` so I'm not sure why it's not working.

Here's my controller code:

```
$scope.allSubjects = Restangular.all('subjects').getList().then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error getting all subjects'));

console.log($scope.allSubjects); // -> Promise {$$state: Object}

function handleSuccess(data) {
  return data;
}

function handleError(error) {
  return function() {
    $log.warn(error);
  };
}
```

However, if I resolve my data it works properly

```
.state('subjects', {
    url: '/subjects',
    templateUrl: 'components/subjects/list.html',
    controller: 'SubjectsListCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    resolve: {
      getSubjectsResolve: function(Restangular) {
        return Restangular.all('subjects').getList().then(handleSuccess..., handleError...);
      }
    }
  })
```

I'm so lost! I don't get it.

Comment: In your handleSuccess, you are returning the data. Who are you returning it to? Typically, your success function would look like: function handleSuccess(response) { $scope.data = response.data; }

Comment: Got it! Do you want to submit that as an answer so I can accept it as the correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your handleSuccess, you are returning the data. Who are you returning it to? Typically, your success function would look like:

```
function handleSuccess(response) {
    $scope.data = response.data;
}
```